# Updating TextBox Value with PHP

Tags: php, html

Before I start let me just say that I have only just started using php this week so I'm still figuring things out. What I am working on is a virtual slot machine.

What I want to do is set the inital value of the credits the user has to 1000 and then subtract their bet from the credits if they lose or add their bet to their credits if they win. I'm only interested in how to deduct the credits as I am sure once I understand this I can do the addition myself.

Can this be done using stritctly PHP or do I need to incorporate Javascript as well?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Virtual Slot Machine</title>
    <link href="slots.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Virtual Slot Machine</hi>

    <form id="slots" method="post">
     <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name">
     <label>Bet:</label><input type="text" id="bet" name="bet" value="100">
     <label>Credits:</label><input type="text" name="credit" readonly="true" value="1000">       
     <input type='submit' value='Spin the wheel' />
    </form>


<?php

isset($_POST["credit"]) ? $credit = $_POST["credit"] : $credit = "";
isset($_POST["bet"]) ? $bet = $_POST["bet"] : $bet = "";
$credit=$credit-$bet;
$faces = array (
'<img src="images/fruit1.png">',
'<img src="images/fruit2.png">',
  );

$wheel1=rand(0,1);
$wheel2=rand(0,1);
$wheel3=rand(0,1);

$result1=$faces[$wheel1];
$result2=$faces[$wheel2];
$result3=$faces[$wheel3];

echo $result1 . ' ' . $result2 . ' ' . $result3 . "<br />";

?>
</html>
```

Comment: Set a variable at `1000` and deduct from there.

Comment: Your need persistence for subsequent requests, so either have a database (overkill) or set a [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) variable at `1000` and deduct from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

If you think about how things get run i.e. the script starts at line 1 and works its way through, you can set the initial values of `$credit` and `$bet` if the values do not exist in $_POST i.e. its the first time they ran this script.

Then all you need to know is that you can add php code almost anywhere in the file using 
`<?php ... ?>` so instead of setting the value="1000" you can use `value="<?php echo $bet;?>"` to use the current values of `$bet` and `$credit` after you have worked them out.

```
<?php

$credit = isset($_POST["credit"]) ? $_POST["credit"] : 1000;
$bet    = isset($_POST["bet"]) ? $_POST["bet"] : 100;
if ( isset($_POST["credit"]) ) {
    $credit -= $bet;
}

$faces = array (
'<img src="images/fruit1.png">',
'<img src="images/fruit2.png">',
  );

$wheel1=rand(0,1);
$wheel2=rand(0,1);
$wheel3=rand(0,1);

$result1=$faces[$wheel1];
$result2=$faces[$wheel2];
$result3=$faces[$wheel3];

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Virtual Slot Machine</title>
    <link href="slots.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>
    <h1>Virtual Slot Machine</hi>

    <form id="slots" method="post">
     <label>Name:</label><input type="text" name="name" id="name">
     <label>Bet:</label><input type="text" id="bet" name="bet" value="<?php echo $bet;?>">
     <label>Credits:</label>
         <input type="text" name="credit" readonly="true" value="<?php echo $credit;?>">       
     <input type='submit' value='Spin the wheel' />
    </form>

<?php 
     echo $result1 . ' ' . $result2 . ' ' . $result3 . "<br />";
?>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the number of credits in a PHP session, so that the number can be remembered between requests.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['credits'])) {
    $_SESSION['credits'] = 1000;
}

if (isset($_POST['bet'])) {
    $_SESSION['credits'] -= (int) $_POST['bet'];
}

?>

...
<label>Credits:</label><input type="text" name="credit" readonly="true" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['credits']; ?>">
...
```

This way, you wouldn't need to keep posting back the number of credits.